# Font rem sizing in H1 header acting strange

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a tagline above my header using a header class tagline. However, changing the font-size on the main h1 css makes zero changes, while the tagline class changes any time I changes its size. I'm confused as to why my header is unresponsive, any help is appreciated. I'm trying to make it somewhat similar [to this W3C example](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html) (example 5).

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1.tagline {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="tagline">Homepage for</h1>
<h1>My Name</h1>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. The text size of both H1 elements are different

Comment: the h1 is 3em, the h1.tagline is 1.5em, both as specified in your css.  Can you clarify what's not working as you expect?

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that the h1 stays exactly the same size whenever you edit the code. It's completely unresponsive to font-size: changes past 1rem I think.

Comment: You're using `em` in your example, not `rem`

Comment: Do you have other css that might be overriding this?  em or rem both work: https://jsfiddle.net/s89rtvhm/

Comment: You are right, I copied over one of my attempts to troubleshoot, my apologies. Even when using rem, changing the value does nothing from what I can see.

Comment: could the html tag be overwriting the h1 sizing vs. the class calling the html size as a reference? The only other thing that calls h1 in my css just establishes font families. I've made a workaround by establishing a second class for the main part of the header which seems to be resizing correctly. Now I have:

`h1.tagline {
        
font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: -18px;
}

h1.main { 
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the `tagline` change size in relation the `h1`? If yes, put all text into *one*  h1 tag, use a `span` for the tagline, a `<br>  for the line break and a value smaller than`1em`for tagline. Now the tagline font-size will change in relation if you change the`font-size`for`h1`

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 > span.tagline {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="tagline">Homepage for</span>
<br>My Name</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the html from W3C example 5, I assume you need the CSS for it.

Here is my crack at it.

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

header {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

header p,
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0.75;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header h1{
  font-size: 5em;
}

header h1 + p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Magazine of the Decade</p>
  <h1>THE MONTH</h1>
  <p>The Best of UK and Foreign Media</p>
</header>
```